# Potential leak when calling addSubview [iPhone]

Tags: iphone

I'm making an app that changes between many XIBs. Although Leaks tool doesn't call it out, whenever I load a new view, the program's memory footprint gets larger and larger.

If I comment out:

```
[self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
```

the program's memory use doesn't change.

Relevant code:

```
- (void)setPage{
[currentView release]; //retained
switch (pageNumber) {
    case 0:
        currentView = [[TheViewController alloc]
                       initWithNibName:@"PageX"
                       bundle:nil];
        break;
    ///Page 1, Page2, etc.
}
for (clearingView in [self.view subviews]) {
    [clearingView removeFromSuperview];
    //[clearingView release]; = crash
}
[self.view addSubview:currentView.view]; //Leaky
}
```

I'm using one view controller.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a subview, its retain count goes up.  I don't see where you are removing the currentView.  If you have retained it previously, and then release it in this function, that won't remove it from the view.

Try putting a [currentView removeFromSuperview]; as the first line and see if that helps.

```
- (void) setPage {
    [currentView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [currentView release];

    switch (pageNumber) {
        case 0:
            currentView = [[TheViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageX" bundle:nil];
            break;
    }
    for (clearingView in [self.view subviews])
        [clearingView removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
}
```

**Edit 1**:
Actually, I see that you are removing currentView along with all other views in the for loop.  That being the case, I really don't see any issue with your code at all.  The only thing I can guess is that somehow the retain count of your ViewController or View is getting bumped up some where else.

> When a low-memory warning occurs, the UIViewController class purges its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the viewDidUnload method to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded with the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. Typically, if your view controller contains outlets (properties or raw variables that contain the IBOutlet keyword), you should use the viewDidUnload method to relinquish ownership of those outlets or any other view-related data that you no longer need.

Comment: In this case, it shouldn't matter if it gets released at the top or bottom.  What do you mean by crashes at the bottom?  On which line? With what error?

Comment: (Sorry I deleted previous comment. Was fighting with comment system.) If I call [currentView release]; right below addSubview, the app crashes. Could my errors be related to the fact that this code is contained within TheViewController?

Comment: Ah right... that makes sense, I was forgetting currentView was a controller, not the view itself.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code... The view should be released in your loop below, but perhaps something is messed up when the controller gets released before the view itself.  Give this a try; see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Tried your new code, and it still has the problem. Thank you for your help, by the way.

Comment: Still has the memory leak?  But no crashing?

Comment: Perhaps there is a memory problem in the controller or view itself.  I'll post a quote from the docs in the answer above...

Comment: I think you're on the right track that the problem lies elsewhere. I added some releases for some XIB elements to some setPage function and now the leak is tiny. Just gotta' find what I missed, I bet.

Comment: Sweet, ya memory bugs are such a pain to find.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obvious I can spot in the code, but the naming is a little confusing and do you really need to retain currentView. If you are using currentView somewhere else it could be that by doing so you are adding to the retain count which would cause a leak.

Here's what I would be inclined to do (Note; I'm typing this on the fly so it may not be 100% correct!):

```
- (void)setPage{

    // Presuming you only want one subview at a time.
    [[[self.view subViews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];

    UIViewController * newController = nil;
    switch (pageNumber) {
    case 0:
        newController = [[TheViewController alloc]
                       initWithNibName:@"PageX"
                       bundle:nil];
        break;
        ///Page 1, Page2, etc.
    }

    [self.view addSubview:newController.view];
    [newController release];
}
```

I don't think you need a class variable (currentView) and this is nicely contained within the method.

Comment: currentView is retained because it crashes unless I release it at the top of the function. Oddly, I was just looking at the retain counts, and it's always 0 at the start of the function, and 1 at the end even if I leave out release.

Comment: Ahh, I just checked some code in a working project and I'm pushing the controller onto the navigation stack so I don't need to retain it. I do remember reading that retain counts cannot be trusted. The reason you might be seeing a retain of 1 at the end is because of the way IOS stacks up UI changes and animates them. It might not actually be releasing until after it's updated the interface which will not happen until the next runLoop cycle.